# How to save detached element and return?

Tags: jquery

I need remove element and return it . Why this code does not show the data of the element to the console

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
         var remElem;
         if ( remElem ) {
            remElem.appendTo( ".box-tocart .actions" );
            remElem = null;
         } else {
             remElem =  jQuery('.box-tocart #product-addtocart-button').detach();
         }
        console.log(remElem.html());
}
```

Comment: provide html element

Comment: button element is class or id ? $('button') not working if you not give . or # in $('')

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy sure it'll work - it is an element selector and will return all`<button />` elements.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I had to var remElem; set before click function

Comment: you are right @benM. But was I thinking button is class or id .

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the definition for `remElem` outside of your function, because it is privately scoped for each click of a button element at the moment:

```
var remElem = null;

$('button').on('click', function(){

    if ( remElem != null)
    {
       remElem.appendTo( ".box-tocart .actions" );
       remElem = null;
    }
    else
    {
        remElem =  jQuery('.box-tocart #product-addtocart-button').detach();
    }

    console.log(remElem.html());
}
```